# java backtracking recursion (Knights)

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking

This is like the N-Queen problem. 
Given size of board (row, col)
and number of knights to be places (knights)

How many arrangement of knights can I fit in the given board ?

I will be using nested int array

1 will represent the knight is occupying that place.

99 will represent place where no knights can move into since existing knight attacks.

0 will represent an empty spot where knight can move into.

After running the debug, I found out that knights(3,3,5);

[-1, -1, -1] [-99, -1, -99] Here, I am stuck and I have to backtrack. [-99, -99,-99]

But in back tracking, see how position of board[0][0] knight will attack --> board[2][1]

And, board[0][2] knight will attack --> board[2][1]

So when I backtrack and undo the knight at the board[0][2],

it also undo -99 which should not have since there was more than one knight attacking that space simultaneously...

I would appreciate any tips or suggestions to get around this problem.

```
public class knightsPlacement {

    public static void knights(int row, int col, int knights) {
        if(row < 0 || col < 0 || knights < 0) {
            System.out.println("Enter new parameters");
            return;
        }

        int [][] board = new int[row][col];

        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < board[0].length; y++) {
                board[i][y] = 0;
            }
        }


                solveKnights(board, 0, 0, knights);


    }

    public static boolean solveKnights(int[][] board, int row, int col, int knights) {


        if(row < 0 || row >= board.length || col < 0 || col >= board[0].length) {
            return false;
        }
        if(board[row][col] == -1 || board[row][col] == -99) {
            return false;
        }


        board[row][col] = -1;
        knights = knights -1;


        if(knights == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        if((row-2) >= 0 && (col-1) >=0 ) {
            board[row-2][col-1] = -99;
        }
        if((row-1) >= 0 && (col-2) >= 0) {
            board[row-1][col-2] = -99;
        }
        if((row-2) >= 0 && (col+1) < board[0].length) {
            board[row-2][col+1] = -99;
        }
        if((row-1) >= 0 && (col +2) < board[0].length) {
            board[row-1][col+2] = -99;
        }
        if((row+2) < board.length && (col-1) >=0 ) {
            board[row+2][col-1] = -99;
        }
        if((row+1) < board.length && (col-2) >= 0) {
            board[row+1][col-2] = -99;
        }
        if((row+2) < board.length && (col+1) < board[0].length) {
            board[row+2][col+1] = -99;
        }
        if((row+1) < board.length && (col+2) < board[0].length) {
            board[row+1][col+2] = -99;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(board[i]));
        }
        System.out.println();


    for(int rowCount = 0; rowCount < board.length; rowCount++) {
        for(int colCount = 0; colCount < board[0].length; colCount++) {
                            if(solveKnights(board, rowCount,colCount, knights))return true; 
                        }
                    }



            board[row][col] = 0;
            knights = knights +1;

            if((row-2) >= 0 && (col-1) >=0 ) {
                board[row-2][col-1] = 0;
            }
            if((row-1) >= 0 && (col-2) >= 0) {
                board[row-1][col-2] = 0;
            }
            if((row-2) >= 0 && (col+1) < board[0].length) {
                board[row-2][col+1] = 0;
            }
            if((row-1) >= 0 && (col +2) < board[0].length) {
                board[row-1][col+2] = 0;
            }
            if((row+2) < board.length && (col-1) >=0 ) {
                board[row+2][col-1] = 0;
            }
            if((row+1) < board.length && (col-2) >= 0) {
                board[row+1][col-2] = 0;
            }
            if((row+2) < board.length && (col+1) < board[0].length) {
                board[row+2][col+1] = 0;
            }
            if((row+1) < board.length && (col+2) < board[0].length) {
                board[row+1][col+2] = 0;
            }

            return false;

    }

}
```

Comment: The for loop to initialize your 2d array is unnecessary.  `int` has a default value of 0, so this will be the default value for your board cells.  Since you are interested in the number of possible layouts you are probably interested in a number.  So `solveKnights` should return `int` instead of `boolean`.  You don't need to use 99 value if you write a method that checks if a position is valid or not.  You can do this by scanning the horizontal and vertical line for the presence of a 1 value. That should simplify your backtracking.

Comment: You may also want to decide if your solution should keep permutations of the same solution or not.  I'm guessing you aren't interested in the same solution where knight 1 and knight 2 are switched in position for example.

Comment: Oh I am not interested in the permutations as you said. I am just interested in different arrangements of knights (assume knights are all the same, not permutable their order does not matter). Thank you so much for the feedback. I will take off from where you left me.